# merge two tuples with same key

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples

I have a list that contains two indices for each entry, along with a value. The first two elements in each tuple are the row and column in the table, respectively. The third item is the cell's value.

I want to merge the values of each of the same cells. Here is an example of the data structure:

```
[
    (1, 2, 'R'),
    (1, 3, 'S'),
    (1, 2, 'S'),
    (2, 3, 'S'),
]
```

I need to merge the items with matching row/column pairs like this:

```
[
    (1, 2, 'RS'),
    (1, 3, 'S'),
    (2, 3, 'S'),
]
```

or:

```
[
    (1, 2, ('R', 'S')),
    (1, 3, ('S',)),
    (2, 3, ('S',)),
]
```

Comment: for member in myList:
    out=[]

    for i in range(0,len(myList)):
        for j in range(0,len(myList)):

            if (member[0].myList[i]==member[0].myList[j]) and (member[1].myList[i]==member[1].mylist[j]):
                newlist=[(member[0],member[1],(member[2].myList[i],member[2].myList[j]))]
                out.append[newlist]
            else:
                out.append(member)
                print(out)
                   
#I am very basic in python, probaly I have a lot of problem in this code. I will appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should work. If you're using Python 3, change the`.iteritems()`method calls to just`.items()`(which is already an iterator in that version of Python).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_final_values(values):
    mergeddict = defaultdict(list)
    for group in values:
        mergeddict[group[:-1]].append(group[-1])
    return [(k + (tuple(v),) if len(v) > 1 else k + tuple(v))
                for k, v in mergeddict.iteritems()]

test = [(1, 2, 'R'), (1, 3, 'S'), (1, 2, 'S'), (2, 3, 'S')]

print(merge_final_values(test))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, ('R', 'S')), (1, 3, 'S'), (2, 3, 'S')]
```

if you want the merged values concatenated into a single string, just change the return value of the function to:

```
    return [(k + (''.join(v),)) for k, v in mergeddict.iteritems()]
```

And you'll get this output instead:

```
[(1, 2, 'RS'), (1, 3, 'S'), (2, 3, 'S')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just small note: dict.iteritems() is replaced by dict.items() in python 3.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby()` :

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = [(1, 2, 'R'), (1, 3, 'S'), (1, 2, 'S'), (2, 3, 'S')]
>>> g_list=[list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l),lambda x :x[0:2])]
>>> [(i[0],j[0],k) for i,j,k in [zip(*i) for i in g_list]]
[(1, 2, ('R', 'S')), (1, 3, ('S',)), (2, 3, ('S',))]
```

in this snippet we first need to sort our list with `sorted()` function that that sort our tuplse based on those elements , so we have this result :

```
>>> sorted(l)
[(1, 2, 'R'), (1, 2, 'S'), (1, 3, 'S'), (2, 3, 'S')]
```

then we grouping the sorted list based on first tow element (`lambda x :x[0:2]`) so we would have :

```
>>> g_list
[[(1, 2, 'R'), (1, 2, 'S')], [(1, 3, 'S')], [(2, 3, 'S')]]
```

So now we have a nested list with same 2 first element , now we need to keep just one of 1th and 2th element and both (or more) 3th elements , in this situation we could use `zip()` function that will have this results :

```
>>> [zip(*i) for i in g_list]
[[(1, 1), (2, 2), ('R', 'S')], [(1,), (3,), ('S',)], [(2,), (3,), ('S',)]]
```

now what we need is chose the 0th element of first and second tuples and whole of 3th elemnt :

```
(i[0],j[0],k) for i,j,k in ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry for my code was not proper format. I was  did not know formatting rules!

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]:     a=[(1, 2, 'R'), (1, 3, 'S'), (1, 2, 'S'), (2, 3, 'S')]
   ...:     b={}
   ...:     for i in a:
   ...:         try:
   ...:             b[i[0:2]] += (i[2],)
   ...:         except(KeyError):
   ...:             b[i[0:2]] = (i[2],)
   ...:     c=[k + (v,) for k, v in b.items()]
   ...:

In [2]: a
Out[2]: [(1, 2, 'R'), (1, 3, 'S'), (1, 2, 'S'), (2, 3, 'S')]

In [3]: b
Out[3]: {(1, 2): ('R', 'S'), (1, 3): ('S',), (2, 3): ('S',)}

In [4]: c
Out[4]: [(1, 2, ('R', 'S')), (1, 3, ('S',)), (2, 3, ('S',))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation using a dictionary:

```
dct = {}

for *i, j in lst:
    dct.setdefault(tuple(i), list()).append(j)

[(*k, tuple(v)) for k, v in dct.items()]
# [(1, 2, ('R', 'S')), (1, 3, ('S',)), (2, 3, ('S',))]
```